# PHP replace multiple occurrences of domain in curl response using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I use preg_replace in PHP to change multiple occurrences of a domain in href tags using regular expressions.

I need only the relative path of the link. The code I have removes everything including the url path and query parameters.

Current Link appearence

```
<a href="https://www.website.com/LUGAD-Clothing-Jewelry-Shoulder-Brushed/dp/B07D1V99MF/ref=sr_1_3/131-4937141-2376367/s=apparel&ie=UTF8&qid=1531422091&sr=1-3&nodeID=7141123011&psd=1&keywords=clothing%2Cshoes+and+jewelry">The Link</a>
```

Desired Link appearence

```
<a href="/LUGAD-Clothing-Jewelry-Shoulder-Brushed/dp/B07D1V99MF/ref=sr_1_3/131-4937141-2376367/s=apparel&ie=UTF8&qid=1531422091&sr=1-3&nodeID=7141123011&psd=1&keywords=clothing%2Cshoes+and+jewelry">The Link</a>
```

I have tried this

```
$html = $this->curl->getContent($completeUrl);

$newhtml = preg_replace('/<a(.*)href="([^"]*)"(.*)>/','<a$1href="/"$3>',$html);
```

**In summary.
I would love to use regex to convert all occurrences of the absolute href to relative href**

Comment: Would it not be more suitable for you to use str_replace? - `$html = str_replace('https://www.website.com/','',$html);` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Avoid using `.*` in your regexp, it's greedy and will match across multiple anchors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing from you question you should use a regex like this:

```
(<a\s+href\s*=\s*")(?:https?:\/\/)?www\.website\.com\/
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/PQ3yLL/1)

```
preg_replace('/(<a\s+href\s*=\s*")(?:https?:\/\/)?www\.website\.com\//i', '$1', $str);
```

This builds on your idea to use the a-href as an anchor for the replacement.
We cannot really use a lookbehind to assert the a-href before the URL since there can be arbitrary whitespace and PCRE does not support variable length patterns in lookbehinds.
Therefore, I capture the front and put it back in the substitution using `$1`.

If you have to deal with other attributes before the `href` you could use:

```
(<a(?:(?!href).)* href\s*=\s*")(?:https?:\/\/)?www\.website\.com\/
```

[**Demo 2**](https://regex101.com/r/PQ3yLL/2)

Comment: Tried both and they all work. Since I did have other attributes before the href tags, I took the second one. It works like a charm. Thanks a great deal.